# Unexpected repetition while extracting integers from string in c++ using stringstream

Tags: c++, input, int, stringstream

I am trying to read a file which consist of lines that are made of space separated integers. I want to store each line as a separate vector of integers.
so I tried reading input line by line and extracting integers from it using

```
stringstream
```

The code I have used for extraction is as follows -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line)) {
    int temp;
    stringstream line_stream(line); // conversion of string to integer.
    while(line_stream) {
        line_stream >> temp;
        cout << temp<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Above code works but it repeats the last element.For example, input file -

```
1 2 34
5 66
```

output:

```
1 2 34 34
5 66 66
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The usual error not testing the extraction, use: `while(line_stream >> temp) cout << temp<< " ";`

Comment: The same problematic pattern is analyzed very well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong . It covers C++ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this:

```
while(line_stream) {
    line_stream >> temp;
    cout << temp<< " ";
}
```

which fails for the same reason that `while (!line_stream.eof())` would fail.

When you have read the last integer, you haven't reached the end of the stream yet - that will happen on the next read.

And the next read is the unchecked `line_stream >> temp;`, which will fail and leave `temp` untouched.

The proper form for such a loop is

```
while (line_stream >> temp)
{
    cout << temp<< " ";
}
```